# Unable to log into stackexchange.com

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, stackexchange.com, myopenid

I am not able to log into stackexchange.com - specifically, this url: https://stackexchange.com/users/authenticate

I receive the message:

> **Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:**
>
> No OpenID endpoint found.

My OpenID endpoint is [my domain](http://www.jaredharley.com), and it's working just fine, as I *just* created an account over at the new [Electronics beta](http://electronics.stackexchange.com) (and subsequently, [asked this question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/account-merge-request) to have my two existing accounts merged). I've been able to log out and back in of several different Stack Exchange sites using my domain, just not on the stackexchange.com site.

I also had my brother try and log into stackexchange.com from his work using his custom  domain, and he had the same message and wasn't able to log in either.

For what it's worth, I *am* able to log in if I click the "MyOpenID" button (I am directed to the "hey, we don't recognize you, want to create an account?" screen).

Comment: Also, does the "global auto-login" normally work on stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

SE's web.config was missing a section which is included in other sites across the network.

Comment: Is this fix live on all stackexchange sites? I'm still having this exact problem on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/