# Unable to log into stackexchange.com with Clickpass

Tags: support, openid, login

My problem is very similar to the one described in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66073/unable-to-log-into-stackexchange-com), but it was marked "Fixed" and I'm still having this problem.

I am not able to log into stackexchange.com, other StackExchange sites on subdomains of stackexchange.com, or others like serverfault.com with Clickpass.

I receive the message:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

No OpenID endpoint found.
```

Clickpass seems to be working just fine, as I just logged into [another site](http://news.ycombinator.com/) with it.  I'm still logged into stackoverflow and meta.stackoverflow with clickpass, but it looks like my serverfault account doesn't have my alternate Google openid associated with it, because when I try to log in using Google, it brings me to the "hey, we don't recognize you, want to create an account?" screen.  But I don't want to do that.

I tried using both the Clickpass button and typing in `http://clickpass.com/public/<username>` manually.

Please help!  I don't want to lose my StackExchange accounts for the ones that I haven't associated an alternate openid with.

Comment: Clickpass is suddenly working again. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1):

Having this issue again.
I get this error:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> No OpenID endpoint found.

Instead of

```
http://clickpass.com/public/<username> 

http://www.clickpass.com/public/<username>
```

seems to work.